# (procedural) Edgewear for (procedural) real Microdisplacement? for Cycles

Tags: edges, displacement, procedural

I would like to make a **procedural shader** for **glazed, worn ceramics**.

Right now I am using **real micro displacement** to create the prodruted parts and I am using the geometry node, bevel and a math node set to dot product to detect edges. Got it from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMMy-xqrwdw).

I also found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21G2l2EYhLY) edge detect node setup from Wayward Art Company, but It doesnt work for me and is far to complex for me to understand what is happening inside.

This is what I got so far.
I am wondering if this is the right approach.

Thanks,

Paul

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please show pictures? Does it mean you want to fake small details around the edges? Does it mean you want to create fake displacement (with Bump node), not real displacement (with the Displacement node)? Is it for Cycles, Eevee?

Comment: ah sorry sure, will update the question! my bad

Comment: so you're trying to find the different ways, and the best way, to have this kind of effect, i.e. edgewear on angles? Also, what are you planning to use, Eevee or Cycles? Some methods don't work with Eevee...

Comment: Yeah exactly. Yes, im in cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are several ways to do what you are trying to do, some only work with *Cycles*.

- The first one is the one you cite which mixes the *(Input) Geometry > Normal* output and *Bevel* nodes into a *(Converter) Vector Math* in *Dot Product* mode:

[image]

- You can use the *Geometry > Pointiness* output:

[image]

- Or the (Input) *Ambient Occlusion* node (it works with *Eevee*, you'll need to enable the *Ambient Occlusion* option in the *Properties* panel > *Render*:

[image]

To make the effect more natural you can mix it with a *Noise* or another texture, here through a *MixRGB* in *Lighten* mode:

[image]

All these black & white textures can be used as factor in a *Mix Shader* or *MixRGB* node in order to mix two sets of nodes.

At last you have some group nodes like the one you cite and that you can upload. There is the **Mask** node, as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSOMqOmnwEY), and the **Edge Detect** node, as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21G2l2EYhLY), both created by Wayward Art Company.

Comment: Hey :). Would it be possible to add some examples of this effect on displaced geometry? Seems like that's one of the things the OP is asking about :).

Comment: Cool :). I was just curious, since I don't have much experience with displacement and want to learn :).

Comment: actually I thought he wanted to know how to make the edgewear effect (link to his video), I'm not sure about the displacement thing, I may have missed something...

Comment: Yeah thats it :) Kept on playing with the settings and got some good results by now! Thank You!